# How can I quickly create Javadoc links to elements in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts, javadoc

I want to easily create links to classes, methods, fields, etc. from within my Javadocs without having to type out the full expression e.g., `{@link AllowAllHostnameVerifier}`.

What is the fastest way to do this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. If you don't already have a Javadoc for the element you're documenting, press
    <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
2. Using the `AllowAllHostnameVerifier` example, from within the Javadoc comment where you'd like the link, use autocomplete:  Type `AAHV` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
3. Select `{@link AllowAllHostnameVerifier}` from the list of autocomplete options by pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: if you have shorter class names you can type the full name and `Control + Space`, so the `{@link Whatever}` is inserted without having to select it from a list

Comment: True, I'll mention that.  I just wanted to spread the word about the `CamelCase` autocomplete feature :)  You'd still have to select it from a list though because Eclipse offers the class name by itself or the `{link class}` options.

Comment: you're right, I replied without actually trying it since I automatically press `Enter` after `Control + Space`, so I don't even get to see the list!

Comment: I was used to exactly this behaviour, but now with Juno, I find that only the class name is completed, w/o any {@link ...} around. Any idea why? Bug, or configuration that I have messed up?

Comment: @stolsvik You can keep pressing Ctrl+Space to cycle through, eventually you should see the `{@link ...}` in the content assist box.  You can re-enabled links showing in the default box in Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced, then check "Java Proposals" to show in the default box.

Comment: How can i make eclipse automatically use the full path to the linked class to avoid the import statement?

Answer (score 10):

As an addition, you can also create links to methods by using `{@link #` Ctrl+Space for methods in the current class, or by using `{@link ClassName#` + Control Space for methods in ClassName.