# How do I have Intellij automatically convert a class name to a @link in Javadocs?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Eclipse allows autocompleting a class name when writing Javadoc text, the result being that the the inserted text contains the full class name inside a `@link` tag. See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9908634/1911095

Can IntelliJ IDEA be set up to behave in the same way? I can autocomplete class names in Javadocs, but only if I first type or autocomplete the `@link` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Space/Ctrl+Shift+Space [works just fine](https://i.imgur.com/fRkdCu6.gifv) in IntelliJ IDEA 2018 to complete class name links inside JavaDoc.

Comment: Is it a recent feature? I'm still on 2016.3